# Javascript Variable Scope: Why variable is increased on every refresh?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert(name);
function init() {
    name = parseInt(name) +1; // name is a local variable created by init
    function displayName() { // displayName() is the inner function, a closure
        alert (name); // displayName() uses variable declared in the parent function    
    }
    displayName();    
}
init();
</script>
</head>
<body>
Some  Text 
</body>
</html>
```

This is my simple JavaScript Code. I just copy/pasted the above code and refreshed multiple times to see strange output.

Every time I refresh the page, I can see name variable is increased by 1.

First load     :   alerts  ' '  and  1 
Second load    :   alerts   1  and  11  
Third load     :   alerts  11  and 111  
and so on ...

If I close the window or tab and then reload, it appears to work correctly. But, again, on the second reload in the same window or tab, results in the same output as mentioned above.

My question is: why and how the variable `name` is available even after refresh and multiple refreshes as well (<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)?

Comment: What you have described should not be possible. Can you setup a demo on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Regarding your comments, `name` is **not** a local variable. It is declared without a `var` statement and therefore lives in the global scope (i.e. a global variable).

Comment: Under what browser? Also, `name` is global (window).

Comment: Define your name variable with keyword `Var` otherwise it will be treated as global variabale

Comment: Thanks all, for your time in making me understand the above problem. 



Matt : http://jsfiddle.net/sLpLL/  Here is the jsfiddle url 



ComFreek : Yes, name is in global scope but, the alerts on multiple refreshes  amazed me

DaveNewton  : I tried  the above example in Mozilla and Chrome 

RohitVyas  : Yes, If I declare var name,  then  Result was as expecting.  But  If  I am not declaring  var name,  then  it seems  in User Agent  name is already lexically available which might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `name` to `n_ame` and it will work :)

`name` is a global variable in my Chrome, so it' not reset after a refresh

Comment: Yes  changing  the variable  name  from "name"  to "name1"  made it clear,  Thanks for the Help